# Facebook share fails to submit share popup form returning an ajax error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have added a SHARE BUTTON for every page in my site using the button generator in their developer site for button_count type of SHARE BUTTON: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button/

The OG data have been placed right (the decription, title, link, and thumbnail) in the popup of share form, but whenever I submit it, it fails. when I check the console log of that window popup, it has console error..

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) https://www.facebook.com/ajax/sharer/submit_page/
```

Is this an issue in facebook? I have been using their widget but just now it seems to fail...
Have I done something wrong?

```
<?php
function getUrl() {
    $url  = @( $_SERVER["HTTPS"] != 'on' ) ? 'http://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"] :  'https://'.$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"];
    $url .= ( $_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] !== 80 ) ? ":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] : "";
    $url .= $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    return $url;
}

$share_url = getUrl();
?>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo addslashes($share_url);?>" data-type="button_count"></div>
```

As for my `$share_url`, I have also tested it not to addslashes or urlencode or hard code it and these are the results:

```
echo "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] //OG Data is Error 404
echo $share_url //Facebook Internal Server Error when Submit
echo addslashes($share_url) //Facebook Internal Server Error when Submit
echo urlencode($share_url) //OG Data is Error 404
echo urlencode("http://example.co/article-1.php") //OG Data is Error 404
```

Comment: `addslashes` _and_ `urlencode` are both nonsense here – the _context_ you are putting the data into here is _HTML_, so `htmlspecialchars` is the only thing that makes sense for outputting the data as value of the `data-href` attribute.

Comment: still didn't work with that.